# error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, floating-action-button

i'm new to android. when i want to import a project into my android studio it complain about this error that :
**error**
package android.support.design.widget does not exist

here is my code :

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

// Setup FAB to open EditorActivity
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CatalogActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
}
```

and this is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.pets"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
     compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.9.1'
}
```

how can i solve this problem and one another thing that every time that i want to import another else project into my android studio there is bunch of error and need to change build.gradle and build.gradle.properties and every time i have some problem like this . can anyone give me a reference about this build.gradle to learn how it should be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Floating action** buttons are used for a special type of promoted action.  so you need to add  `com.android.support:design library`
Include this line also in your build.gradle:

compile this `dependencies` in your `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Floating action** buttons are used for a special type of promoted action.  so you need to add  `com.android.support:design library`
Include this line also in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following in gradle file :

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

Comment: Not all need. Only compile `'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` is require.

Answer (score 1):

When using the later Android Gradle plugin versions such as `7.0.3`, I had to do the following steps to resolve this error:

1. Add `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` to the module level `build.gradle` file. You'll get an error about needing to migrate to AndroidX.
2. Migrate the project to AndroidX via 'Refactor' -> 'Migrate to AndroidX' -> 'Migrate'
3. Once the migration is complete, go through all relevant files containing import references to `android.support.design.widget` and replace them with `com.google.android.material.textfield` in the `java` folder and `layout` folder.

Hope this helps anyone!

Answer (score 0):

FloatingActionButton is available in com.android.support:design library. If you are using any class that class related libraries you need to include in build.gradle, that's why you are getting error.